# Unable to set value to None unless set to string first

Tags: python, numpy, nan, nonetype

I Have a list of pandas series: `stagedInserts`.

I'm looping through each key-value in each series within a list to (among other things) weed out any `np.nan` values and set the value to `None`.  This is carried out as follows:

```
# %%
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# %%
stagedInserts = [
    pd.Series({"one": 3, "two": 4, "three": np.nan})
]
print(f"stagedInserts: {stagedInserts}")

for i, vals in enumerate(stagedInserts):
    for j, val in enumerate(vals): 
        if(np.isnan(stagedInserts[i][j])):
            print(f"stagedInserts[i][j] {stagedInserts[i][j]}")
            stagedInserts[i][j] = None
            print(f"2stagedInserts[i][j] {stagedInserts[i][j]}")
```

Though not particularly elegant, I would expect this to be an entirely reasonable way to convert `nan`s to `None`s.  However the second print statement returns a nan.  I've confirmed this with an additional `np.isnan()` as well.

This would be confusing enough but I found that if I set first `stagedInserts[i][j] = "Test"` and THEN `stagedInserts[i][j] = None`, the second print statement yields a `None` as I wanted.  (See below):

```
for i, vals in enumerate(stagedInserts):
    for j, val in enumerate(vals): 
        if(np.isnan(stagedInserts[i][j])):
            print("it's still nan")
            print(f"stagedInserts[i][j] {stagedInserts[i][j]}")
            stagedInserts[i][j] = "Test"
            print(f"2stagedInserts[i][j] {stagedInserts[i][j]}")
            stagedInserts[i][j] = None
            print(f"3stagedInserts[i][j] {stagedInserts[i][j]}")
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Please update your question with a small sample of `stagedInserts`

Comment: You wrote that you have a list of dictionaries. So inside stagedInserts you have "val" dictionaries whose keys are integers starting with 0? Otherwise you'd get a keyerror.

Comment: With a sample list of dicts that would not throw an error running your code: [{0:np.nan},{0:np.nan}] I can't reproduce this behavior. Please provide a sample.

Comment: @srn You're quite right in both your comments!  I was wrong about the object type in the list.  It's actually a list of pandas series.  I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @quamrana Sample data has been added.

Comment: A Series with float `dtype` can hold a number or `nan`.  An object dtype can hold strings, numbers, and None,

Comment: @hapulj That explains it.  I was under the impression that float was compatible with None.   So the proper way to handle this is to change the datatype first.

Comment: This is not a reasonable way to do this, actually. You shouldn't be using `for i, val in enumerate(some_series)`. `myseries[i]` should only be used for *label based indexing*, however, `pd.Series` objects fall back to positional indexing, but this is deprecated behavior, and will throw an error in future releases

Comment: But taking a step back: *why do you want to convert `Nan` to `None`?*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Honestly, because I'm saving my data to a MySQL database in a really hacky way that blows up when it encounters a nan.  This problem was the last straw; I just did a refactor to use sqlalchemy that basically renders this issue moot and allowed me to throw out a lot of bad code.